# Do Pattern match and extract fixed length file to compare against different table column

Tags: teradata

Thanks in advance for helping through this blog.
I am working on a Teradata SQL requirement and need help here. Below are the details.

```
1. S_SRV_REQ_X has a column ATTRIB_47 which has different values like below.
Record 1: ,233650289942,803632139926
Rec 2: ,307503494667,,657001028536
Rec 3: 010000768233,010000768241,
Rec 4: 010000768233,010000768241,
Rec 5:,,,517971957017,
Rec 6: ,,002512117934,301040153878,,573977796362
Rec 7: ,002402799494,,,,,,,
and so on..
```

The above are the Access Card numbers which I have to look in a different table column S_ASSET Table, column: SERIAL_NUM(which will have only one record per line) and find status in the S_ASSET Table for that Serial num and populate the SR_NUM for disconnected cards only.

Is there any way I can do only pattern match for the Access Card numbers and populate the SR_NUM for the DISC cards?

Access cards numbers are always 12 digits, and they are comma-separated.  But the comma could be any where in the record. The max length of the ATTRIB_47 column is 255, so any record could have max 15+ cards.

I should have this condition in the where clause. Can somebody shed some ideas on this please??

Conditions:

```
AND SSRY.CST_OU_ID = s_asset.owner_accnt_id;
AND S_ASSET = S_SRV_REQ_X.ATTRIB_47(do pattern match here to look for each access card numbers in the table).
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an additional condition using equality you might simply use a LIKE:
SSRY.CST_OU_ID = s_asset.owner_accnt_id AND S_SRV_REQ_X.ATTRIB_47 like '%' || S_ASSET || '%'

But if this is the only join condition you'll get a product join, which will consume huge CPU for large tables. In that case better split the values in rows before joining, depending on your Teradata release this might be more or less easy.

Btw, you probably know, that a repeating group violates 1st normal form and thus is really bad practice.

Dieter